# Get PID/VID nunbers from any usb device

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, usb

I am learning linux-kernel and driver, and just a newbie. I want to write a "driver" which can get PID/VID of any usb device, then print those numbers into kernel log.

As far as i know, USB HCI detects PID/VID from attached USB device,and pass to usbcore, even if it does not have right driver. So there must be some APIs to get it, but I dont know.

Any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please use 'lsusb' to get those details